# Iterate through a collection of JSON Objects

Tags: java, json, netbeans

I have a JSON file called `mani.json` which contains several objects, each object containing 3 key-value pairs that have information about some artifact files.

```
{ "art_src_path": "source/subdir/hi-there.txt","art_id": "6945-L9.txt","art_date": "2018:03:10 01:10:33"}
{ "art_src_path": "source/hello-world.txt","art_id": "10426-L13.txt","art_date": "2018:03:10 01:10:33"}
{ "art_src_path": "source/subdir/testfile.txt","art_id": "50518-L66.txt","art_date": "2018:03:10 01:10:33"}
```

I want to iterate through each of these objects in another file called `FileTest.java` and get the value corresponding to `art_src_path`. My `FileTest.java` file contains code that looks like this:

```
<!-- language: java -->

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject a = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("mani.json"));

for (Object o : a ) {
   String path = (String) o.get("art_src_path");
   File myFile = new File(path);  
   System.out.println("Source path: "+path);
}
```

NetBeans prompts an error and states that the object returned by the parser is not iterable and so I cannot use the for-each loop.

While this code, with certain modifications, worked well for iterating through an `array` of objects, it seems to fail for iterating through an `object` of objects.

So I have 2 questions:

1. What does the parser return; so that it is iterable for an array but not for an object?
2. How can I iterate through all the objects in `mani.json` to get the value for `art_src_path` from each object?

Almost all the answer so far tell me how to iterate over an array of objects. I am able to do that. I need to know how to iterate over an object of objects.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is mani.json file is correctly json format? If so, the list would be JSONArray. JSONArray can iterate but JSONObject cannot.
If mani.json file is not json format but just text file. read line by line and parse each as JSONObject.

```
        String strJson = "[{ \"art_src_path\": \"source/subdir/hi-there.txt\",\"art_id\": \"6945-L9.txt\",\"art_date\": \"2018:03:10 01:10:33\"},"+
"{ \"art_src_path\": \"source/hello-world.txt\",\"art_id\": \"10426-L13.txt\",\"art_date\": \"2018:03:10 01:10:33\"},"+
"{ \"art_src_path\": \"source/subdir/testfile.txt\",\"art_id\": \"50518-L66.txt\",\"art_date\": \"2018:03:10 01:10:33\"}]" ;

        System.out.println("input = "+strJson) ;

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser() ;
        JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(strJson) ;

        for (Object o:a) {
            String path = (String) ((JSONObject) o).get("art_src_path") ;
            System.out.println("source path:"+path) ;
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing before, and it was working but that's when I have an "array" of objects in the JSON file, which is like your strJson.

Comment: You were right. The JSON file wasn't in the correct format. The code that I was using earlier, and the one you posted works like a charm now. Thank you.